# Mysql today date

Tags: php, mysql, date, select

I want to select only records with today's date?  I'm using this query:

```
$query = mysql_query (
    "SELECT
        tentego_img.*
    FROM
        tentego_img
    INNER JOIN tentego_img_vote ON tentego_img.id = tentego_img_vote.object_id
    WHERE
        cat = '".$cat [ ' id ' ]."'
    GROUP BY
        tentego_img_vote.object_id
    ORDER BY
        SUM(
            (
                CASE
                WHEN tentego_img_vote.vote = '0'
                AND DATE(date) = DATE(NOW()) THEN
                    '1'
                ELSE
                    '-1'
                END
            )
        ) DESC
    LIMIT 1"
);
```

In this excerpt code:

```
(CASE WHEN tentego_img_vote.vote = '0' AND DATE(date) = DATE(NOW()) THEN '1' ELSE '-1' END)
```

How do I select on today's date?

Comment: Show your database schema

Comment: ...and don't use PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Answer (score 3):

This is your query, fixed up:

- To use table aliases.
- To `GROUP BY` the field from the more obvious table.
- To avoid numeric values in single quotes

Here is the query:

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM tentego_img i INNER JOIN
     tentego_img_vote iv
     ON i.id = iv.object_id
WHERE cat = '".$cat['id']."'
GROUP BY i.id 
ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN iv.vote = 0 AND DATE(date) = DATE(NOW())
                  THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If you want votes only from today, then move the condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM tentego_img i INNER JOIN
     tentego_img_vote iv
     ON i.id = iv.object_id
WHERE cat = '".$cat['id']."' AND
      DATE(date) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY i.id 
ORDER BY SUM(CASE WHEN iv.vote = 0
                  THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

An even better way is to use inequalities rather than a function:

```
WHERE cat = '".$cat['id']."' AND
      (date >=  CURDATE() AND
       date < DATEADD(CURDATE(), interval 1 day)
      )
```

This is better because it can make use of an index on `date`, if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, change the dateformat to match the format you are using in your database:

```
(CASE WHEN tentego_img_vote.vote = '0' AND STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y') > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 1 DAY) THEN '1' ELSE '-1' END) //where 'date' is the column name of the date you're checking.
```